# No definition found in vscode for system libraries

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to vscode so I'm not sure if this is possible, but in visual studio you can cmd+click into a method and see the definition. In VS code, when I try to see the definition, it says no definition found. For example

```
using System.Collections;
```

when I try to see the definition for "Collections", it says "no definition found". How can that be? This is a system library. Does VS code even support this feature of jumping into a library?

Comment: Maybe try  System.Collections.Generic  or System.Collections.ObjectModel  OR better yet google for the answers

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood what VSCode is. I expected it to be an IDE but it's really just a glorified text editor. I don't think what I'm asking is possible.